# Function to bootstrap sample and generate standard error (SE)

Tags: r, for-loop, statistics-bootstrap

I have a 100 probabilities that are associated with four unique individuals (AAA:DDD) that I have created and displayed here.

```
IndID <- as.factor(rep(c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD"),25))
Prob <- runif(length(IndID),0,1)
Data <- data.frame(IndID, Prob)
Data <- Data[order(Data$IndID),]

> head(Data)
   IndID      Prob
1    AAA 0.5860417
5    AAA 0.1824266
9    AAA 0.3301014
13   AAA 0.5048122
17   AAA 0.3717195
21   AAA 0.9090825

> summary(Data)
 IndID         Prob        
 AAA:25   Min.   :0.01341  
 BBB:25   1st Qu.:0.19743  
 CCC:25   Median :0.48315  
 DDD:25   Mean   :0.50475  
          3rd Qu.:0.81789  
          Max.   :0.99805
```

I want to bootstrap (sample with replacement) the probabilities the for each individual AAA:DDD. For each iteration I want to discretize the probabilities to 0’s and 1’s using a 0.50 cut off and then sum the vector.

I have created the function below which discretizes and sums.

```
BiSum <- function(x){
    IndBi <- ifelse(x >= 0.50, 1,0)
    SumIndBi <- sum(IndBi)
    }
```

I want to apply the function to the probabilities for each individual in a for() loop and use the boot() function as seen below.

```
require(boot)

SE <- numeric(length(unique(Data$IndID)))
for (i in unique(Data$IndID)){
    IndProbs <- Data$Prob[Data$IndID == i]
    b <- boot(IndProbs, BiSum, R=10)
    SE[i] <- sqrt(var(b$t))     #This is a roundabout way to grab the SE from a boot() object
        }
```

While I think the function BiSum is correct it is incorrectly incorporated into the `for()` loop and `boot()` function.  The loop above results in the error:

```
Error in statistic(data, original, ...) : unused argument (original).
```

My goal: for each individual (AAA:DDD) I want to bootstrap Prob, discretize them using 0.50 as a cut off, and sum the resulting 0’s and 1’s.  I want to do this R=10 (only low for example but will repeat R=10000 with real data) times for each AAA:DDD and then extract the standard error of the `boot()` object.

Suggestions on how to improve my loop above would be appreciated.  Specifically how to correctly incorporate the ”statistic” argument to `boot()` within the loop.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include index argument `idx` for the `boot` function

```
BiSum <- function(x, idx){
     IndBi <- ifelse(x[idx] >= 0.50, 1,0)
     SumIndBi <- sum(IndBi)
}
```

Also, to get SE, it may be cleaner to use `sd(b$t)` instead `sqrt(var(b$t)`

Comment: Thanks a bunch @TWL.  Adding an idx works great.  As seen in the output of SE included here there are four extra 0.00000 in addition to the IndID's.  Any thoughts on where they come from?  Thanks again.     `> SE
                                                  AAA      BBB 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 2.436967 2.312056 
     CCC      DDD      EEE`
2.487526 2.381884 2.497726

Comment: To follow your example, in the for loop you are indexing the factor levels AAA-DDD, while the numeric vector SE doesn't have the names assigned. The function doesn't know where to put the values, and simply concatenates the output with the SE vector. You have to assign names of the levels to the vector before running the for loop <code>names(SE) <- unique(Data$IndID)</code>